# Applescript - Automator - tomorrow keyboard shortcut

Tags: applescript, automator

I've been able to successfully create a keyboard shortcut from a "quick action" in Automator based on running AppleScript (inserts current system date). However, I cannot get a similar script to work for inserting tomorrow's date (current date + 1 day) or the day after (current date + 2 days).

Here's what I have:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set thedate to (current date) as string
    set myNewDate to thedate + (1 * days)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke myNewDate
    end tell
end run
```

It produces this Syntax Error:

[image: Can’t make "Tuesday, March 5, 2019 at 10:13:55 AM" into type number.]

Can someone help me identify my error and fix it? Apple support won't help with AppleScript-related issues for non-developers.

Any help is greatly appreciated by this novice coder.

Thank you to Allan, Ɱark Ƭ, Wowfunhappy and others for the quick help (not just a fix, but defining my syntax issue). I have a modification: how do I tell the string to leave off the time stamp at the end: "at 12:24:21 AM" ?

Comment: Right off the bat...you're attempting to add an integer to something you defined as a string.

Comment: @JustinS, Please do not add additional questions after the original has been answered. One question per question. Create a new question for "how do I tell the string to leave off the time stamp at the end: "at 12:24:21 AM" ?"

Comment: Nonetheless let me add... please take the time to read thoroughly the **Class Reference** section for the [**date**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCGECID) _object_ in the **AppleScript Language Guide** as it will give you insight with how you can retrieve just the parts of what's returned by the `current date` _command_, e.g.: `set thedate to date string of ((current date) + (1 * days)) as string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add the day in the wrong spot. Try this:

```
set thedate to ((current date) + (days * 1)) as string
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke thedate
end tell
```

The "current date" returns the time in seconds, so you have to add one day worth of seconds (86,400 seconds in a day, but I'm sure you knew that) to get tomorrow. Change the multiplier to get more days in the future or past by using a negative value for the multiplier.

Note that not all days have 86400 seconds (DST change is +/- 3600, Leap seconds, etc…) so on some days it may be an hour off.

Comment: I might add... it's not that you *can't* add to the date later, but it has to be done before the date is turned into a string. Once the date is a string, you can't perform arithmetic on it. "My dog is fluffy." + 1 doesn't equal anything, and so neither does "Tuesday, March 5, 2019 at 10:33:22 AM" + 1

Comment: This also works: `set thedate to (current date) + (1 * days) as string`

Comment: @user3439894: There is always more than one way to do something. In this case using a system provided constant is better than using a "magic number". I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the prompt help. I have lots to learn and am excited to do it! What about a way to tell the (current date) to leave off the time stamp part of the string: "at 12:24:21 AM" ?